# Trying to delete a file from Apache2 not in /var/www

Tags: apache, apache2

I am new to `apache2` and am having permission issues with respect a functionality of my website.

I have `django` running `apache2` and my `django` project has a DELETE functionality on the website, where the back-end deletes a folder from /Project/results . Following is my python function which works as expected when I just run it on the `django` web development server but throws error `'Exception: ', OSError(13, 'Permission denied')` when I run it through `apache2`,

```
def delPrevGraph(request):
    delId = request.GET["delId"]    
    try:
        print("Path deleting: /Project/results/",delId)
        shutil.rmtree("/Project/results/"+delId)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: ",e)          
    args={}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(args))
```

The permission and owner of the `results` directly is as follows,

```
drwxr-xr-x 52 www-data www-data 4096 May 19 06:41 results
```

But all the folders within `results` directory are owned by `root`. Just for checking I did try to chown and give permissions as below but showed no difference.

```
chown www-data:www-data deleteID
chmod 755 deleteID
```

Also I tried to adding the following in the `default-ssl.conf` file and tried restarting the `apache2` and deleting from the website. Still no difference.

```
<Directory /Project/results/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I cannot change the location of the this directory and place it in `/var/www`.

Is there a way to to get this done? I am stuck at this issue for a while now and would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the shutil documentation. And in the box of warning, they advice us to doesn't use copy functions on POSIX (linux) system. Maybe your problem is relation with a POSIX bug, try to use the basic I/O files functions.